# Explain what happens when a user logs onto a website

Tags: web, web-applications, authentication, logonserver

What happens behind the scenes when a user logs on to a website. I have tried searching but couldn't found the answer. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

when a person login to your website. the browser sends the credentials to the server and server check for the required data and when it finds the correct match. it gives true result and if not then it gives false results.

**User -> Enter Data To Browser ->  Browser send data to the server -> server check the data -> do the operation which is sets.**

Comment: I need the answer in more detail

Comment: please clear what do you want know? coding method or process